# Most Valuable Circle Chords

Tags: code-golf

This challenge was inspired by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ChrisKlerkx/status/1408140074089435140).

### Idea

Consider a circle with `n` evenly spaced dots around the perimeter, where each dot has a postive integer value:

[image: dots]

Now connect the dots with *non-intersecting* chords:

[image: suboptimal]

Next consider our score, which is the sum of the products of these pairs.  When `n` is odd, the extra orphan dot will not contribute to our score.

Finally we ask: Which pairing of dots gives us the highest score?

[image: optimal]

### Task

Write a program to solve this puzzle.

#### Input

A list of postive integers, in order, representing the values of the dots which are spread evenly around the circumference of a circle.

#### Output

A list of pairs of the same integers, representing an optimal solution to the puzzle described above.

That is, the pairs you return must:

1. Produce non-intersecting circle chords when connected by straight lines.
2. Produce a maximal score among all possible solutions that satisfy rule 1.

The score we're maximizing is the sum of the products of the pairs, and for odd-length input does not include the unpaired number.

In some cases, such as `[1, 9, 1, 9]`, the optimal solution will voluntarily leave unpaired numbers.  In this example the solution is to pair the two `9`s and leave the two `1`s as singletons.

Additional notes:

- Again, for odd-length input, the unpaired number won't contribute to your score.  You may include this singleton in your output or not.
- Same goes for "voluntary" singletons such as the `[1, 9, 1, 9]` described above.
- In addition to the optimal list of pairs, you may include the optimal score value as well, but don't have to.
- If 2 or more solutions tie, you may output any one of them, or all of them.
- The order in which the optimal pairs are given doesn't matter.

### Rules

This is code golf with standard site rules.  Both input and output formats are flexible.  In particular, output may be:

- An array of arrays, where the inner arrays have length 2.
- An n by 2 or 2 by n matrix.
- A single flat list, so long as all the optimal pairs are adjacent.
- Anything else reasonable.

### Test Cases

I included optimal score for convenience but it's not required in the output.

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Output: [[2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
Score: 140

Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Output: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
Score: 100

Input: [1, 4, 8, 7, 11, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6, 10]
Output: [[4, 3], [6, 10], [8, 7], [11, 9], [2, 5]]
Score: 237

Input: [12, 8, 2, 20, 16, 7]
Output: [[12, 8], [2, 7], [20, 16]]
Score: 430

Input: [29, 27, 23, 22, 14, 13, 21, 7, 26, 27]
Output: [[29, 27], [23, 22], [14, 7], [26, 27], [13, 21]]
Score: 2362

Input: [1, 9, 1, 9]
Output: [[9, 9]]
Score: 81
```

Comment: Suggest `[1, 9, 1, 9]` -> `[[9, 9]]`

Comment: @att Nice clarification.  I added the test case and a note in the output spec.

Comment: @pajonk It is mentioned in the question twice. *Now connect the dots with non-intersecting chords:*, *1. Produce non-intersecting circle chords when connected by straight lines.*

Comment: I'm confused on the voluntary singletons.  Would we still count the 1s even though they're unpaired?  Why would that be if we don't count a leftover singleton in the odd-dot case?

Comment: @gregsdennis You never count any unpaired singleton.

Comment: If that's the case, then the optimal solution for `[1,9,1,9]` would be `[[9,9],[1,1]` yielding a score of 82.  Ignoring the 1s only gives 81.

Comment: Oh! But they can't cross!  NVM got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <sup><s>27</s></sup> 26 bytes

```
JŒcŒPŒc_€/ṠÆḊ¬Ʋ€ẠƊƇịZPSɗÐṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r6KTko5MCgGT8o6Y1@g93Ljjc9nBH16E1xzYB@Q93LTjWdaz94e7uqIDgk9MPT3i4s@H////RhjoKljoKxjoKhgY6CkaxAA)

-1 byte thanks to @caird.

Independently arrived at something very similar to [Jonathan Allan's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231247/78410).

The only difference is `_€/ṠÆḊ¬Ʋ` part, which tests if two pairs of indices are two non-intersecting chords.

Because of how `ŒP` (powerset) and `Œc` (unordered pairs) generate the results, it is sufficient to filter out the pairs of pairs which have the element-wise ordering of `[[1, 3], [2, 4]]`, `[[1, 2], [1, 3]]`, `[[1, 2], [2, 3]]`, or `[[1, 3], [2, 3]]`. The pairs `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]` should be kept intact. [Test this condition.](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98k6OikZCB6uLMl/lHTGv2HOxccbnu4o@vQmmObjrX//w8A)

```
_€/ṠÆḊ¬Ʋ    Given a 2x2 matrix of values, test if they're valid chords
_€/Ṡ        Sign of cartesian pair-wise difference
    ÆḊ      Determinant
      ¬     1 if zero, 0 otherwise
```

Comment: You can steal [Jonathan's golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/231247/revisions) to save a byte: use `ịZPSɗÐṀ` instead of `ị³ZPSƊÐṀ`, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r6KTko5MCgGT8o6Y1@g93Ljjc9nBH16E1xzYB@Q93LTjWdaz94e7uqIDgk9MPT3i4s@H////RhjoKljoKxjoKhgY6CkaxAA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <sup><s>45</s></sup> 43 bytes

```
ṖẎƤṚ+"JpẎ€¥"Ʋṭ@€"J,€¥ɗẎṭḷ
Jçƒ0RWW¤Ẏị¹ZPSƊÐṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzmkPd/UdW/Jw5yxtJa8CIPtR05pDS5WObXq4c60DkK3kpQMWOTkdKAcUe7hjO5fX4eXHJhkEhYcfWgIS3N19aGdUQPCxrsMTHu5s@P//f7SxjoKRjoKpjoKJjoKFjoJBLAA)

Uses a modified `f(n)`, which is defined as sets of chords containing the vertex `n`.

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 45 bytes

```
ṖṚ+"JpẎ€¥"Ʋṭ@€"J,€¥ɗẎ;ṛ/{ṭḷ
Jçƒ0RWW¤Ṫị¹ZPSƊÐṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY29SsRAFEb7PMUl1QwzzGbizyaIINilWrRYMKSIkMhKWJYYZcVGLBVELBS0VYRFGxsd7bIQ8DHGF4l3xqBbzTfnfPfe/awojttWqxut7pgbTfTH5ffZc/3oNq9avWxgdiNuydctujWt7nsnaPT7mxPNn5prb2s4rB@0munPi1rtDLab8/mVVqdtmxPpUScnIXUYPh5lPSJZTgJKGZHcSMOl4T7yvuF@x4UQ1gbGhsyMow2ttctgHeI4SeyC/@ybbBED8nvTtIXoStjitrtQtlYU6UFF7FiRVTBdMLuHVSdHYyizIzI1tTId72Umbg5crOPcH5mkoxJ82saSwzKHgEOfg8SPz2GFQ8hhicMqIi/5AQ)

Painfully long, but runs pretty fast.

Basic algorithm is to compute all the possible sets of chords (as indices) via memoization. Let's define `f(n)` as the list of all possible sets of chords using first `n` nodes, i.e. `1..n`. `f(0)` and `f(1)` contain a single empty set, and `f(2)` is `[[], [[1, 2]]]`. Also, let's define `f(0..n)` to be `[f(0), f(1), ..., f(n)]`. Then the following recurrence holds:

```
f(n+1) = f(n) ++
  cartesian product of f(0) and (1 + f(n-1)), with [1, n+1] added to each set ++
  cartesian product of f(1) and (2 + f(n-2)), with [2, n+1] added to each set ++
  ... ++
  cartesian product of f(n-1) and (n + f(0)), with [n, n+1] added to each set
```

where `++` is list concatenation and `+` is vectorized addition.

```
ṖṚ+"JpẎ€¥"Ʋṭ@€"J,€¥ɗẎ;ṛ/{ṭḷ    Aux. dyadic link: left=f(0..n), right=n+1
Ṗ                              H = f(0..n-1)
 AAAAAAAAAAbbbbccccɗ           A(H) `b` (H `c` n+1)
 Ṛ+"J                          Reverse H and add 1..n (zipped)
     pẎ€¥"                     Cartesian product by concatenation with H
           ṭ@€"                Zipped append the following to each set:
               J,€¥            [1,n+1], ..., [n,n+1]
                    Ẏ          Collect lists of sets into one list of sets
                     ;ṛ/{      Combine with the sets without n+1
                         ṭḷ    Push into f(0..n) to get f(0..n+1)

Jçƒ0RWW¤Ṫị¹ZPSƊÐṀ    Main link: arg=a list
J                    Indices of the list
 çƒ0RWW¤             Reduce over it using the aux link, starting from [[[]]]
        Ṫị¹          Take the last result; convert the indices to actual values
           ZPSƊÐṀ    Find the set of chords with the highest sum of product
```

Probably I can golf it by *not* taking the right argument of the aux link (which is simply the length of the left arg), but I don't want to torture myself further...

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>28</s>  27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
JŒcŒPŒcZFṢƑ<QƑƊƊ€ẠƊƇịZPSɗÐṀ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers and yields a list of all most valuable lists of chord-end pairs.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r6KTko5MCgGSU28Odi45NtAk8NvFY17GuR01rHu5aAGS1P9zdHRUQfHL64QkPdzb8//8/2tBIR8FCRwFIGhnoKBia6SiYxwIA)** Very inefficient.

#### How?

```
JŒcŒPŒcZFṢƑ<QƑƊƊ€ẠƊƇịZPSɗÐṀ - Link: list A
J                           - get indices -> [1,2,...,length(A)]
 Œc                         - pairs
   ŒP                       - powerset
                   Ƈ        - filter keep those for which:
                  Ɗ         -   last three links as a monad:
     Œc                     -     pairs
                €           -     for each:
               Ɗ            -       last three links as a monad:
       Z                    -         transpose
        F                   -         flatten
              Ɗ             -         last three links as a monad:
          Ƒ                 -           is invariant under:
         Ṣ                  -             sort -> x
             Ƒ              -           is invariant under:
            Q               -             deduplicate -> y
           <                -           (x) less than (y)?
                 Ạ          -     all?
                    ị       - index into (A)*
                         ÐṀ - keep those maximal under:
                        ɗ   -   last three links as a dyad* f(entry, A):
                     Z      -     transpose (the entry)
                      P     -     product (vectorised across this transposed entry)
                       S    -     sum (of those products)

                              * Note: ị takes A on the right Implicitly due to the next
                                      link in the chain (ZPSɗÐṀ) being dyadic (which
                                      it does not need to be), this saves a byte.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>114</s> <s>98</s> <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
f@r_:=SortBy[f@Drop[r,#]~Append~r[[#]]&/@Subsets[j=0;++j&/@r,{2}],Dot@@-#&]~Last~{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYu9TsMwFIX3voalLD0V8U3a0KIigzoyVAqbZSFTEjUV@ZHjDiiKV0YelUcIN7AyXJ2j77untv5c1NZXJztNpXIvu33eOv/4oUt1cG2nHYQJD11XNG/BaS2MiW5Ufn3tC9/ryz6@Wy4vTBwGGg0OrVdqJb6/PiMTnmzvwzBOR1c1XovVfakEju/XXqnnqi44FBMThfxkmzAsBokt@EbMlZAgxRobZLj9F/6hlG0GObs17xN2Mv5VxIZAMSS/z4S2oAyUgAgyheQieUsbxuNinH4A)

```
j=0;++j&/@r                     range over input
Subsets[ % ,{2}]                get pairs
f@Drop[r,#]                     recurse on values not between indices
           ~Append~r[[#]]        and append chord
                         /@ %    for each pair
SortBy[ % ,Dot@@-#&]~Last~     get the set of chords with the highest sum of products,
                           {}   if there are no chord sets (i.e. len(r)<2), return an empty set
```

Since `-` has lower precedence than `` (`Transpose`), `Dot@@-#&` is interpreted as `Dot@@(-(#))&`, which turns out to be equivalent to `Dot@@(#)&` since the negatives cancel out.

Here's a walkthrough for when `f` is called on `{1,8,2,9}`:

```
r                       =   {1, 8, 2, 9}
j=0;++j&/@r             =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
Subsets[ % ,{2}]        =   {1,2}       {1,3}       {1,4}       {2,3}       {2,4}       {3,4}
map:
    Drop[r,#]           =   {    2 9}   {      9}   {       }   {1     9}   {1      }   {1 8    }
    r[[#]]              =   {1 8    }   {1   2  }   {1     9}   {  8 2  }   {  8   9}   {    2 9}
    Append[f@ %2 ,      =   {{2,9}      {           {           {{1,9}      {           {{1,8}
            % ]         =    {1,8}}      {1,2}}      {1,9}}      {8,2}}      {8,9}}      {2,9}}
sorting function:
    Dot@@-#            =   26          2           9           25          72          26
SortBy[ ... ]~Last~{}   =                                                   {{8,9}}
```

Comment: If you get a chance I'd like to see an explanation.

Comment: @Jonah Added. The written explanation felt lacking, so I hope the walkthrough illustrates what's going on...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>[135](https://tio.run/##RYxNCsIwEIWvMsuJzcK0oljoSYZZRNposE1LrDA5fUx04eKDx/vb0v5YQ5ezG2a73EYL0gvYMMJiBcmhkOlZcUNEQkfWQp6Zm1/gWX2Vb2rJrRE8@ADRhvuERs9TQFGK9XNK//vXe8FUrg6JDNdNqpvSWyNx3qIPOzqk9qqhvRS6QqvBnApVGw3VPteYlcof)</s> 117 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and max([[[x[0],v]][:i]+f(x[1:i])+f(x[i+1:])for i,v in enumerate(x)],key=lambda y:sum(a*b for a,b in y))
```

-18 thanks to @ovs and @dingledooper

thanks to @EliteDaMyth for earlier correction

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsIwDIbvfQofG/ChCYyNSDxJ5EMqUq3aGlAbUNqX7@wA22kX64//z47t65w@L3G3rt3p2w/t2UO2GXw8w@Bz7ZzLriG8Eznb07ars9MsVFH9VltS3WWEHu/QRwjxNoTRp1BnRfgV5lfP2U63ofabFoT22Ao9K7WmMKXp5JxGMAg7hD3CG8IB4R3hA@FIWP1jPp194TihHxgDxwIzppsCmYJwNA3npFzShjHDdYZZw6bmTlq0Lu3MQeznJ4xKJKpk/izTl8ltBXAd@5h44V/Jp1F/L1l84RtuFqdJqhepLoyq1h8)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZAxbsMwDEV3n4JbpIaDpaRJIyAnITi4iN0KjeXAdgHZl3dJNR27EAT/@5@iHsv8OaTDtnXXe9O/3xrIIUOTbtA32RBRppoxU2RmCpH3ncnkpLGli3sX2HbDCBFigrFJH625t8lkaxm/2uUvdQnTd29WCXtZybE6VnUs1g4j8Ta30zxdiRyCRzggHBFeEU4IZ4Q3hAtj9Y/4VI6Fk4H7xQS4FFgwVxfIF0Sqr2Wmdh17wbz4vLBeRCdJTntX4vxJ5ecSQbUyV3pB1gvKy0MF8Bhjmk3GHQTYYadfUG0/) by including the case of not using the first dot in the list comprehension.

Comment: [117 bytes](https://tio.run/##dZDBbsIwEETv@Yq5YZc9xIZCscSXWD44wlGjNgYlBjlfn64NHHtZjWberke@Len7Gnfr2p9//dhdPLLJ8PGC0Wdhrc22dfRwzprBbXuRrWIhqxq2yjjZXycM9MAQEeJ9DJNPQWTp6Ccs75uLme@j8B8dCu2pK/Qi5ZrCnOaztYqgCTvCnvBJOBCOhC/CyVHzT/hK9pVjQz0xBk4VZky1FdIV4alb9sp6sTVjmvc0s5pDxZdU0aqe04cSvx5htEznmtI/l/a1uWmA2zTEJDJtYLAh/hcpm/UP)

Comment: Very nice, both.  I was about to replace `[x[0],x[i]]` with `x[:i+1:i]`, but that doesn't work for the new i=0 case!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
JŒcŒPFQƑ$ƇŒcZFṢƑƊƇƊÐḟị¹P€S$ÐṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r6KTko5MC3AKPTVQ51g7kRLk93Lno2MRjXcfaj3UdnvBwx/yHu7sP7Qx41LQmWAXI39nw////aEMjHQULHQUgaWSgo2BopqNgHgsA)

This is a total mess, extremely inefficient, possibly not working correctly and probably very outgolfable.

*-2 bytes thanks to caird*

Comment: "This is a total mess, extremely inefficient, possibly not working correctly and probably very outgolfable." Have an upvote! I am curious what the big-O is here -- it's slow even for lists of 6.

Comment: `Œc` is an alias for `œc2`, saving 2 bytes